# how to compile .proto + .options file using nanopb

Tags: c, protocol-buffers, nanopb

i wrote an .options file and placed it in the same directory as the .proto file.
then, I tried to compile it (using nanopb compiler) by using the command

```
generator-bin/protoc --nanopb_out=. message.proto -s message.options
```

and got this error:

```
Unknown flag: -s
```

so what am I doing wrong? 
do I need to import my options file in the .proto file?
is there anything else I should do to make it work?

Comment: Check [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nanopb/9piO2wSecMI), i think it may help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google's `protoc` has a special syntax for passing options to the plugins. The plugin options are put as argument to `nanopb_out` and separated from the actual destination path by colon (`:`).

`generator-bin/protoc '--nanopb_out=-v -f message.options:.' message.proto`

However, if your `.options` file has the same name as the `.proto` and is in the same directory, nanopb plugin should automatically find and use it.

Also note that the `-s` flag to nanopb expects a pair of settings on the command line, while `-f` takes a filename. Specifying `-v` is also useful to get detailed messages whether it loaded the options file or not. You can get full list of command line options by running:

```
generator-bin/nanopb_generator --help
```

Comment: For me this does not work. It seams, that the plugin only accepts one parameter. If I try `generator-bin/protoc --nanopb_out=-T -v:. message.proto` I get an error `Unknown flag: -v`. Also your trick with single quotes did not help.

Comment: The plugin itself does accept multiple parameters, but it can be difficult to get them passed through `protoc`. Quoting the whole part should work when used at the shell. If nothing helps, you can always do it in two steps: `protoc -o message.pb message.proto` and `python nanopb_generator.py -T -v message.pb`.

Comment: Thanks! That helped!